# (SQL) Assembling multiple tables of deltas into a single populated view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Lets say I have 3 different tables. Foo, Bar, and Baz. Each tables has the same structure; a timestamp and a data value. We can also assume that each table is synchronized at the top row.

```
Foo                      Bar                       Baz
________________         ________________          _________________
|Time    |Value|         |Time    |Value|          |Time    |Value |       
|1:00    |0    |         |1:00    |10   |          |1:00    |100   |         
|1:15    |1    |         |1:10    |11   |          |1:20    |101   |         
|1:30    |2    |         |1:40    |12   |          |1:50    |102   |         
|1:45    |3    |         |1:50    |13   |          |1:55    |103   |
```

Is there a simple way to to assemble these records into a single view where the value of each column is assumed to be the last known value for each populates the unprovided times?

```
________________________________________
|Time    |Foo.Value|Bar.Value|Baz.Value| 
|1:00    |        1|       10|      100|
|1:10    |        1|       11|      100|
|1:15    |        2|       11|      100|
|1:20    |        2|       11|      101|
|1:30    |        3|       11|      101|
|1:40    |        3|       12|      101|
|1:45    |        4|       12|      101|
|1:50    |        4|       13|      102|
|1:55    |        4|       13|      103|
```

Edit:

What if I wanted to select a time range, but wished to have the last known value of each column brought forward? Is there a simple way to do so without producing the entire table then filtering it down?

e.g. if I wanted records from 1:17 to 1:48, I would want the following...

```
________________________________________
|Time    |Foo.Value|Bar.Value|Baz.Value| 
|1:20    |        2|       11|      101|
|1:30    |        3|       11|      101|
|1:40    |        3|       12|      101|
|1:45    |        4|       12|      101|
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: 2008 at the moment, but it's not a rigid choice. Can change if it is really needed.

Comment: . . The second solution in my answer is probably the better solution.  I want to use window functions to answer this, but it seems to require `lag()` with `ignore nulls`, which SQL Server does not support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 doesn't support `lag()`, much less `lag()` with `ignore nulls`.  So, I think the easiest way may be with correlated subqueries.  Get all the times from the three tables and then populate the values:

```
select fbb.time,
       (select top 1 value from foo t where t.time <= fbb.time order by t.time desc
       ) as foo,
       (select top 1 value from bar t where t.time <= fbb.time order by t.time desc
       ) as bar,
       (select top 1 value from baz t where t.time <= fbb.time order by t.time desc
       ) as baz
from (select time from foo union
      select time from bar union
      select time from baz
     ) fbb;
```

EDIT:

An alternative approach uses aggregation:

```
select time, max(foo) as foo, max(bar) as bar, max(baz) as baz
from (select time, value as foo, NULL as bar, NULL as baz from foo union all
      select time, NULL, value, NULL from bar union all
      select time, NULL, NULL baz from baz
     ) fbb
group by time
order by time;
```

This probably has better performance than the first method.

Comment: If yuou're in the mood to more SQL wizarding, I've edited in a question for another situation I might run into along these lines. :)

Comment: @Mike . . . You should ask that as another question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an another alternative solution as you are using SQL SERVER 2008:

```
SELECT *
FROM    (
            SELECT t, [time], value
            FROM (  SELECT 'Foo' as t, *
                    FROM @Foo
                    UNION
                    SELECT 'Bar' as t, *
                    FROM @Bar
                    UNION
                    SELECT 'Baz' as t, *
                    FROM @Baz
                ) un
            WHERE [time] BETWEEN '1:17' AND '1:48'
        ) AS fbb
PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR fbb.[t] IN (Foo, Bar, Baz)) pvt
```

Comment: Doesn't this produce a `NULL` value for times when a given table doesn't have a given time?

Comment: yes, above all three queries give NULL value since the value field is NUMERIC